# Как проверить innertext или text(jquery) на null

Tags: javascript, функции, текст, null

Есть задача добавляять в список дел , через prompt. Но я не могу выйти нормально из цикла тк innertext or text от propmt при cancel (null) возвращает значение пустой строки "" и условие не выполняется Какое лучше условие поставить или как лучше перебрать функцию

```
var todo = $("#todo");
while(true) {
  var newTask = $("<li>");
  var ask = prompt("Введите дело");
  newTask.text(ask);
  if (newTask.text()  === null) {
    todo.append(newTask);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

HTML ниже

```
<ul id="todo"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт с костылем, иначе append шел не в "реальном времени"

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="todo"></ul>

<script>

function task(){
  ask = prompt("Введите дело");
  if(ask){
 $("#todo").append("<li>"+ask);
 setTimeout(task, 1);
  }  
}
task();

</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое получилось. Но не совсем понятно почему функция работает без цикла ? 
Мы же вроде 1 раз вызываем функцию

Comment: @AidosOmurzakov гугли что такое setTimeout()